# Can one write mean value property with respect to a different measure?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-functions

I would appreciate any insights on this matter;

Let us consider the mean value property for harmonic functions in three dimensional euclidean space. This suggests that the value of a harmonic function at the center of a sphere is the average of values of this function over the entire sphere.

Now suppose I have an ellipsoid which is very skewed in one direction. Can one write the mean value property with respect to a different measure? Furthermore are there any inequalities relating the average of the harmonic function over the whole ellipsoid and the value at the center?

Comment: I think your "different measure" is 
 [harmonic measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_measure).

Comment: Is there a very rough estimate available in the case of an ellipsoid for the harmonic measure at the center?